# Will my page get unindexed by google if i delete it's link from my website

Tags: seo

I am working on a website which is an online webinar training . As the link is removed from the website will it effect the index page?will that page be unindexed by google?

Answer (score 0):

Your page will be ranked higher the more links refer to your page.

Which link do you want to remove?

Do You want to delete www.google.com from your page?

Comment: NO we have a list of webinar topics in our site.. if i remove one of the webinar from the website. will google unindex that page?